# COGNOS REPORT assign dynamically default prompt value with Java Script

Tags: javascript, report, cognos-11

I am working with Cognos 11. I have a list of parameters for a list of users. My problem is that I can't set a default value because each client has different data.
For example: I have a client that has data until NOV-2019 and another FEB-2020.
I need for the report to take the last date available and show the report associated to that date.

I was looking at documentation and it is supposed to be with JavaScript/HTML. I don't know JavaScript/Html.

I have a parameter **p_period** that needs to be loaded with the last date available and a prompt combo box.
Can anyone help me please

Comment: Can you create an expression to see if you can get the value?
Like a new data item called Default Date 
where the expression definition might be: Max([Date] for [User])

Comment: Yes, I already tried to put a Maximum([date] for user. However, at the moment of filtering is not working because I need to filter by the parameter or the max value. When I specify the condition, the parameter becomes obligatory at the beginning of the report and it does not work

Comment: Okay.  Let's try to divide and conquer.  Write one list that works by parameter
 and the other by the max date.  Have a prompt that asks to filter by the parm or the user's max date.  Render the list based on that prompt.  Let me know if that works.  Then we can add some more logic if you want